# How to upload a file to sharepoint with Python REST API

Tags: python, excel, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to move an Excel file from a local folder to a SharePoint folder. I already create an access token and I have access to export files from SharePoint to a local file, but I can't do the inverse.

The code I have now is this:

```
# Replace these with your SharePoint details
site_url = 'company.sharepoint.com/sites/PowerBIInitiative'
access_token = response.json()["access_token"]  # Replace with your actual access token


# Define the file name and its path
file_name = "//DCD02/SourceData/data.xlsx"

# Construct the API endpoint URL
url = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/PowerBI/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Extractions')/files/add(url='//DCD02/SourceData/data.xlsx',overwrite='true')"


# Read the file content
with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
    file_content = file.read()

# Set request headers
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Content-Length":str(len(file_content)),
    "X-RequestDigest": "{form_digest_value}"
    
}

# Send the POST request to upload the file
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=file_content, proxies=proxies)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"File '{file_name}' uploaded successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to upload file. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

But I always getting:

> "Failed to upload file. Status code: 400"

What am I missing?

I expected to have the file in SharePoint folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following code

```
"""
Demonstrates how to upload a small files (up to 4MB in size)
"""

from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_user_credentials, test_team_site_url

ctx = ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_credentials(test_user_credentials)

list_title = "Documents"
folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).root_folder
# path = "../../data/SharePoint User Guide.docx"
path = "../../data/Sample.pdf"
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    file = folder.files.upload(f).execute_query()
print("File has been uploaded into: {0}".format(file.serverRelativeUrl))
```